# Have Visual Studio Setup Project retain registry key on uninstall?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, registry, setup-project

How do I get a Visual Studio Setup Project to:

- create a registry key only if it doesn't exist
- not remove the key on uninstall

Comment: This is the kind of stuff that makes Windows users detest the registry :)

Comment: Are you using a third-party installer?

Comment: @BoltClock: Sadly, we have had customers ask us explicitly to leave some of the registry settings intact so they don't have to remember everything they entered the last time they installed the app.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to leave a mark on the pc which says the software has been installed. This is so we can expire a trial installation. Otherwise the user can uninstall and then reinstall the app and the trial restarts.. not perfect .. is there a better way?

Comment: Little late to the fray, but here's how to not create a value if it already exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392962/visual-studio-2010-update-registry-in-setup-application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click on the Registry key in the setup project and select Properties.

1) To only create the registry key if it doesn't exist, ensure `AlwaysCreate` is False.

2) To not remove the key on uninstall, ensure `DeleteAtUninstall` is False.

Comment: Ahhh, I was looking at the individual registry name/value entry not the key. I'd prefer these options on the name/value properties but the key might suffice. On second look though even if DeleteAtUninstall is False the key will still be deleted if it was created during installation.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this. Dave has mentioned that the values in the key still get deleted even after setting DeleteAtUninstall=false. I have the same issue too,

Comment: If there is a hierarchy of the `Keys` and the topmost `Key` is set as DeleteAtUninstall=true it could override the children's DeleteAtUninstall=false setting.